# Is there a way to search "unversioned files" in JetBrains IDEs (PhpStorm, WebStorm IntelliJ etc)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Before committing my changes, I want to search for common typos, but I don't want to search through my entire project. I can search the files in the default changelist using the `Find window -> Scope -> Default Changelist` (i.e. files that have been modified) but not the ones that are new files which the IDE calls "Unversioned Files".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An idea (if the number of such files is small): you can open all of them in the IDE and then use `Open files` scope when using "Find in Files" or "Code | Inspect Code..." (makes sense to use spellchecker inspection for typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way of doing it. Select the unversioned files and then right-click "Add to VCS". Then you can search in the changelist along with the modified files. Not exactly the answer I was looking for but works for my situation.